# node.js, trying to route sub-domain to specific directory

Tags: node.js, server, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I'm currently using [bouncy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bouncy) to route specific sub-domains to node projects running on different ports like so

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    switch(req.headers.host){
        case "first.domain.com" : bounce(3000); break;
        case "second.domain.com" : bounce(3001); break;
    }
});
server.listen(80);
```

that works fine, but I also want to be able to resolve particular sub-domain's to specific directories like so

```
        case "third.domain.com" : bounce(3001+"/folder"); break;
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but in theory that's what I'm trying to do. I've been looking at [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) but I can't seem to figure out how to use it in this way either.

I'm new to node ( and rolling out "servers" in general ) It's my understanding that I could use ngnix to accomplish this but I was hoping to keep things simple by resolving this within the node server code.

Comment: What do you mean by resolving subdomains to directories?

Comment: @Patosai essentially i want someone to type third.domain.com into a browser and i want them to see the same page that shows up had they gone to second.domain.com/folder ( but i don't want it to redirect, i want the URL in their address bar to remain "third.domain.com" but the content to have been from second.domain.com/folder )

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
case "third.domain.com" : bounce(3001, { path: '/folder' }); break;
```

Comment: just tried this, at first it rerouted to "third.domain.com/folder" displaying the content from "second.domain.com/folder" so it kind of worked ( except with the unwanted side effect of adding /folder to third.domain.com ) ...but then when i tried again it just keeps showing me the root from port 3001 ( ie. the content from second.domain.com ) :( ...could bouncy be the issue? is there a way to do this with better supported node module like http-proxy?

Comment: nginx would make it pretty easy with rewrites.